How do i adjust this spring door closer?
What is the name of this door closer and how do I adjust it? It currently slams the door shut. Thanks.
Spring door closer

This is a pneumatic storm door closer. There is a screw at the end of the cylinder that controls the amount of air leaving the closer. Turning the screw all the way in forces the closer to remain open. Either the closer is not adjusted correctly or it is defective.

There should be an adjusting screw somewhere that closes up a little hole.
There's a chance that the piston is leaking, you may need to get new O-rings for it.

There's also a strong liklihood that the o-rings can't be replaced as the cylinder is welded shut and becomes junk when they go bad.

And the damper can usually be replaced in its entirety...too bad the pic doesn't show the whole thing.
